# How can i copy the data from subdirectories to one level above using Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal, file-copy

I have the directory and file structures like below.

```
path/A/1/a/11.txt
path/A/1/a/12.txt
path/A/2/a/21.txt
path/A/3/a/31.txt
```

I want to copy these files to another path but one level above. Please note sub-directory "a" is  not available in  the new path.

```
path2/A/1/11.txt
path2/A/1/12.txt
path2/A/2/21.txt
path2/A/3/31.txt
```

Since i have multiple directories and under which i have multiple files like these, i cannot simply use the command given below

```
cp -R path/A/1/a/*.txt path2/A/1/
```

Looking for inputs.
Thanks

Comment: path2/A/[1-3]/ directories do not exist. We need to create them while doing copy itself. The note is just highlighting the difference between  path and path2, thats all. In path, we have sub-directory called "a" which we dont have it in path2

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a loop:

```bsh
from=some/path
to=some/other/path2

for dir in "$from"/A/*/; do
  dest=${dir/#$from/$to}
  mkdir -p "$dest"
  cp -v "$dir"/*/*.txt "$dest"
done
```

Note the trailing slash in the pattern in the `for` command: that restricts the results to directories only.